# logrotate multiple files via prerotate script

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have "ansible jobs log DIR" /var/log/ansible where are stored all ansible logs.

e.g.

```
# ll
total 35688
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     5874 May 16 07:28 ansible_20230516_072619.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2937 May 16 07:35 ansible_20230516_073516.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2937 May 16 07:37 ansible_20230516_073654.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2937 May 16 07:41 ansible_20230516_074104.log
...
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    11476 Jun 27 11:14 ansible_20230627_111401.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    33871 Jun 27 11:26 ansible_20230627_111442.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    61888 Jun 27 11:57 ansible_20230627_115531.log
```

I would like to do housekeeping via logrotate :
Because there are too many "small" log files, I would like to compress all files older then 1 month.
So I used prerotate script to move files before rotate to folder /var/log/ansible/archive.
But logrotate not works.
Goal is to have one compressed file for  each month.
This file will contain all logs for particular month.

Here is my conf

```
/var/log/ansible/archive/*.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    monthly
    rotate 30
    maxage 30
    prerotate
        find /var/log/ansible/ -name "*.log" -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /var/log/ansible/archive/ \;
    endscript
}
```

Output:

```
logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.d/ansible
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/ansible/archive/*.log  forced from command line (30 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/ansible/archive/*.log
  log /var/log/ansible/archive/*.log does not exist -- skipping
Creating new state
```

//UPDATE//

OK, I removed prerotate script, looks it started works something, but I cant see any rotated files.
Also as I mentioned earlier, my goal was to rotate / zip all 1 month old files in one file, not each file separately, therefore I used this prerotate script before.

```
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/ansible/*.log  forced from command line (30 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230516_072619.log
Creating new state
  Now: 2023-07-24 13:16
  Last rotated at 2023-07-24 13:00
  log needs rotating
...
renaming /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.1.gz to /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.2.gz (rotatecount 30, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.0.gz to /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.1.gz (rotatecount 30, logstart 1, i 0),
log /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.31.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
set default create context to unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
renaming /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log to /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.1
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
# logrotate.d]#

...

ll /var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.1.gz
ls: cannot access '/var/log/ansible/ansible_20230627_115531.log.1.gz': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have to remove your prerotate script and the
`delaycompress` keyword;
logrotate already compresses your files because of the `compress` keyword

If you look in `/etc/logrotate.d` you will find a number of scripts for logrotate.
In `/var/log` you see their result.
Looking at these you can easily adapt your config file